# Retrieve user data related to my API with Google API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have an API to write some data in a google's spreadsheet. The problem is that to write in a spreadsheet I have to set the spreadsheet url directly in the code.
I know that there's a way to create a new spreadsheet after the user sign in with Google credentials. What I need is to save this new spreadsheet for this user to know if he don't already have an spreadsheet related to my API so I don't need to create a new one.

There's a way to do this automatially with Google API or I will need to create a database linking each user with his spreadsheet ID?

Comment: I would go with linking user with their spreedsheet ID  Google isnt going to do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that you are using the Google Sheets API and that your question is if this API store the links between your app and the spreadsheets created by using it. The answer is no.

It's worthy to note that you could use the Goole Drive API to find the spreadsheets. One option is to add metadata to the spreadsheets to make it easier to find the spreadsheets created by your app.